# Running a remote batch file using psexec through Jenkins fails

Tags: batch-file, automation, continuous-integration, psexec, continuous-deployment

Running a remote batch file using `psexec` through Jenkins fails. Running the same batch file using `psexec` from the slave directly works without a charm.

Let me provide some more information. Jenkins and its slave are in a separate domain than our target machine.

When I run the batch file like this:

```
"D:\Temp\PsTools\PsExec.exe" \\<targetmachine> -u <targetdomain\targetdomainuser> -p <pwd> -accepteula  "d:\temp\remotescript.bat" arg1 arg2
```

directly from the slave (Remote Desktop taking over the machine and opening a command prompt) this works perfectly.

When entering it in a windows batch build step in Jenkins there is no visible output and I just see a spinner but nothing happens anymore and the build hangs queuing any other build creating a massive backlog. Apparently I get a failure audit where my Jenkins user tries to logon to the target machine however I specified a domain user with admin rights on the target machine (a domain user for the domain of the target machine).

Does anyone have any idea why the user tries to logon with any other credentials than the ones provided and why this works running it from the Jenkins-slave directly?

Or any other way of achieving this (running a batch file on the remote machine) is more than welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a notorious issue with psexec:

http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-always-hangs-when-run-from-java_topic5013.html

[Program output lost when passed through PsExec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279809/program-output-lost-when-passed-through-psexec)

You can try with xCmd:
http://feldkir.ch/xcmd.htm 
(it will not work against localhost)

Comment: Localhost is no concern. I had a little trouble on getting the xCmd file due to the false virusalert, but got it running. I need to investigate one small error probably due to passing my arguments.

Comment: I had a trouble with xCmd when connected to 64-bit servers: "Couldn't start remote service
Error:2 - The system cannot find the file specified." Easy way to fix is copying xCmdSvc.exe from C:\Windows\System32 to C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Answer (score 7):

PAExec is a functional clone of PSExec and **lets us see the output via Jenkins etc**.

**http://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/**

XCmd is what we used at HP but for some reason it is not working at my current gig.

I don't know when PAExec appeared but it seems an ideal solution. Soon after discovering it (today) I nailed an intermittent problem with a very long/ involved Jenkins Deployment Pipeline.

Comment: Paul, thanks you very much! I had same issue, that invoking psexec via Jenkins returns only 80 chars to stdout. PAExec works perfect. I see all stdout in Jenkins output!

Comment: @Guillaume~ Thanks for posting this question ! Found it useful after 3 years.
Paul and akozin thanks, I was trying this for over a fortnight ! I don't know how I shall thank you on this.

Comment: Paul, thanks so much...I was trying this since so many days and with your answer I was through in 2 minutes... saved my life..:D

Answer (score 3):

Try this , this will work

```
"D:\Temp\PsTools\PsExec.exe" \\\\remoteMachine -u username -p password /accepteula -h cmd /c "C:\remotescript.bat"
```

Answer (score -1):

try couple things...

1. add parameter option 0 after the accepteula in your command that should kills any existing psexec process which is hung up and start processing your psexec
2. verify the machine for 32-bit or 64-bit..

   for 64-bit the psexec is searched in C:\Windows\system32
   for 32-bit the psexec is searched in C:\Windows\SysWOW64

in jenkins job you can set msbuild version to 64 BIT or 32 BIT accordingly and it should work as expected.